# Decimal to Octal using MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

What is the simplest way to convert **Decimal** to **Octal** using MIPS assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote it this way:

```
    #the octal number is $t2
    li $t6,0 #remainder
    li $t7,0 #final octal number
    li $t8,1 #placeInNumber
    octalToDecimalLoop:
        rem $t6,$t2,8
        div $t2,$t2,8
        mul $t6,$t6,$t8
        add $t7,$t7,$t6
        mul $t8,$t8,10
        bnez $t2,octalToDecimalLoop
```

Comment: divide and remainder by a power of 2 is done much more efficiently with shift / AND instructions.